# Checking DB health in github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

Im running a container with mssql, and want to know if the DB is healthy after a set of second, cant figure out how to return the value of this step that has the docker inspect command in it

> docker inspect --format={{.State.Health.Status}} test-db

so I can tell it in a next step, ex. *the output* == 'healthy' and if this is true then go forward with the steps onto build down the line..

I dont know the format and my head is starting to explode.
If anyone could help me understand how to do this?

EDIT:

I know im close:
[image]

EDIT:
solution was to use those damned single quotes or the $() `docker inspect --format={{.State.Health.Status}} test-db`

Answer (score 0):

try surrounding the `{{` with single quote like

```
docker inspect --format='{{.State.Health.Status}}' test-db
```

and executing in the `if` condition like:

```
if [[ $(docker inspect --format='{{.State.Health.Status}}' test-db) == "healthy"  ]]
```

Comment: I made it work with putting them in $(docker inspect --format={{.State.Health.Status}} test-db)

Comment: Right, I was editing the answer :)